# Show MapPin title on user tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a MapPin class like this

```
//.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapPin : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

AND

```
.m
#import "MapPin.h"

@implementation MapPin

@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;

@end
```

And then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath of my class, I have

```
MapPin *ann = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"HERE";
    ann.subtitle = @"Test";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [riCell.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

And when the user taps on it I want the title and subtitle to show? Is there a method like on MapPin tap? I though it was supposed to occur automoactilly?

How can I show it on the user tap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLGeocoder delegate method and use CLPlacemark object and get the locality and distribute to the annotation accordingly

```
// get the place details from the current location
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                   if (error){
                       NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                       return;
                    }

                   // get all the details of the current location
                   placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                   // set the place details to the annotation
                   annotation.title = [NSString stringWithString:_placemark.subLocality];
                   annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:_placemark.locality];
                   [self.mapView addAnnotation:annot];


                }];
}
```

Comment: if any query , ping me @iqueqiorio .

Comment: Im not sure how this displays the annotation title when the pin is tapped?

Comment: add a gesture on the map view. This is only the delegate method where you can get the location and sublocation title

Comment: I think doesn't answer the question that has been asked .

Answer (score 0):

This is Swift code ... same you need to implement in Objective C

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        /*
            For now, all we have are some quick and dirty pins for viewing debug
            annotations. To learn more about showing annotations, 
            see "Annotating Maps".
        */

        if (annotation.title! == "red") {
            let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView()
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            } else {
                pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Red
            }
            pinView.canShowCallout = true
            pinView.draggable = true
            return pinView
        }
```

canShowCallout = true is the Key here

Comment: can you do this is obj-c or do you not know it? I might be able to convert but how and where do you call this method from the tableview?

Comment: This is MKMapview's delegate method , you need to implement in your viewcontroller which is delegate of your MapView i guess